# Remove redundant ' - Google Chrome" from title bar while opening new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

When I open new chrome window using below code:

```
var newWin = window.open("/", "ABC", "width=200,height=200");
newWin.document.write("<title>ABC</title>");
newWin.document.write("<body>Hello World!</body>");
```

It open with "ABC - Google Chrome " in title bar.

I want just "ABC" in title bar.

Comment: you can't change it

Comment: @epascarello, I have found that in tab title bar it's not adding it.

Comment: @Kanti The second parameter is the window **name** (meaning an ***identifier***, that can later be used to refer to the specific window), and not the window **title**. This is mentioned explicitly here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open. The title bar is set through the `<title></title>` tag of the page that is loaded.

Comment: @PeterB yeah I'm setting with newWin.document.write('<title>ABC</title>') where newWind is returned by window.open method

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the browser appends this onto whatever the developer specifies and it cannot be changed. Even if you did change it for yourself, it would have no effect on your users' browsers.

It actually comes in handy, believe it or not, at the OS level, when you're automating windows to be focused based on title, because you can identify the application from the window's title alone.

For example, in Ubuntu Linux, this command shows me the titles of all open windows and the processes that are associated with them:

```
wmctrl -lp
```

I write scripts that read these titles and do things with windows. It is nice, in this case, to see which windows are `Chromium` for example.

Comment: But this create confusion as in tab it's not appending and in new window it's appending.

Comment: Which ever tab has focus becomes the title bar of the whole browser-window and the browser's name gets appended onto the end of that. I see what you mean, but I see no way to effectively change this behavior for your user's browsers.